# DSE: Unable to sstablellaoding data from 4.8.9 to 5.0.2

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have 5GB worth of data in DSE 4.8.9. I am trying to load the same data into DSE 5.0.2. The command I use is following:

```
root@dse:/mnt/cassandra/data$ sstableloader -d 10.0.2.91 /mnt/cassandra/data/my-keyspace/my-table-0b168ba1637111e6b40131c603254a9b/
```

This gives me following exception:

```
DEBUG 15:27:12,850 Using framed transport.
DEBUG 15:27:12,850 Opening framed transport to: 10.0.2.91:9160
DEBUG 15:27:12,850 Using thriftFramedTransportSize size of 16777216
DEBUG 15:27:12,851 Framed transport opened successfully to: 10.0.2.91:9160
Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: 
InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: at     org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:342)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:156)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:109)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies)
 at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result$execute_cql3_query_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:50297)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result$execute_cql3_query_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:50274)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:50189)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1734)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1719)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:321)
... 2 more
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to load the system keypsace too? They are different in 4.8 vs 5.0 so you shouldn't. Run sstable upgrade just on your user keyspaces: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10996

Comment: Sorry, how would I exclude system keyspaces? My keyspace is my-keyspace and table is my-table. On the hard disk of the source DSE installation, the table location is: /mnt/cassandra/data/my-keyspace/my-table-0b168ba1637111e6b40131c603254a9b/.

Comment: Sorry I see your command now. Hmm are you using the sstableloader from 5.0 or 4.8

Comment: sstableloader 4.8. Trying to load data into 5.0.

Comment: Anybody at DataStax who can help with this?

Comment: Try the 5.0 sstableloader. If that doesn't work, you may have to upgrade sstables before loading.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. Does trying the 5.0 sstableloader mean manually copying the stables over to the 5.0 cluster? Or does it mean copying the 5.0 sstableloader to the 4.8.9 node?

Comment: The latter, pull the 5.0 tarball to the box where your 4.8 sstables are and run sstableloader from there. Have you considered a cluster to cluster migration using spark?

Comment: OK. Downloading the tarball and running it doesn't work: Could not find or load main class com.datastax.bdp.tools.ShellToolWrapper. For the approach that consist on upgrading that sstables, I copied the tables over to DSE5 and ran: "nodetool upgradesstables". I didn't see any change. Anything else I had to do?

Comment: How many nodes?

Comment: If it's just 1 node, just create the schema and move the files over.

Comment: It's two nodes. Can I just move the data to one node and it rebalances? Though I moved the data to one node and it is sitting there in the data folder under the keyspace folder. But when I describe the keyspace, the table doesn't show up. Do I need to do something else to have that loded?

Comment: Migrating from a 2 node cluster to another 2 node cluster?

Comment: If so, 1) create the schema in the 5.0 cluster 2) move both node's data to each new node (into the new cfid tables) 3) nodetool refresh to pick up the data 4) nodetool cleanup to clear out the extra data

Comment: Ok. This procedure worked for me. Please feel free to add this as answer so we can "close" the ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scenarios when you have few nodes and not a lot of data, you can follow these steps for a cluster migration (ensure the clusters are at most 1 major release apart)

1) create the schema in the new cluster

2) move both node's data to each new node (into the new cfid tables)

3) nodetool refresh to pick up the data

4) nodetool cleanup to clear out the extra data

5) If the old cluster was from a previous major version, run sstable upgrade on the new cluster.

Comment: if they're search nodes, also create the solr cores. been bit by this before.

Comment: I have the same issue but on a larger cluster and cluster size is also changing. I cannot simply copy data. Answer provided is only for a small use case and doesn't really answer underlying sstableloader issue raised. I was wondering if anyone was able to find solution to make sstableloader work to stream data from DSE 4.8 to 5.0. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would do a spark powered migration for that use case: http://www.sestevez.com/cluster-migration-keeping-simple-things-simple/